# Which one is the original One Punch Man, the webcomic or the manga?

Tags: one-punch-man

I have been reading *One Punch Man* manga for a while now, and noticed that there's apparently a webcomic on the internet too. Some people told me that the webcomic is original and the manga is headcanon, is it true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, the *Manga* isn't headcanon (Note:A lot of fan made manga does exist). It is a detailed redrawing of the *Webcomic*, with extra chapters occasionally drawn in. The *Webcomic* is way ahead and is more or less the same, word-for-word if compared to the completed chapters of the *manga*.
I personally recommend reading the *manga* first and then continuing with the *webcomic*. However, the webcomic tends to deliver its humor a lot better because of the ridiculous art style.

Answer (score 4):

The original *One-Punch Man* webcomic was created by ONE himself, who also created *Mob Psycho 100*.

For the original webcomics, ONE did the "drawing" himself, and his drawing skills are more or less close to 10-year old kids. Later on *Weekly Young Jump* came to realise the potential of the web-novel and officially did the redraw for the series.

Original Saitama:

[image: This is original Saitama]

Original Genos and Saitama, with Bang:

[image: Original Genos and Saitama]

Comment: Where did you find the original webcomic? Where can I read/buy it?

Comment: Those were pulished on ONE's personal blogs. He removed those after the publication deal.